# Downgrade PHP Version

Tags: linux-mint, php, version

I am running PHP 8 in Linux Mint 19.1. Now I need to run PHP 7. How can I do that ?

[image]

Comment: what messages do you get if you try to install `libssl-dev`? It is mentioned as being the blocking package. Out of preference you should paste the actual text into the body of your question rather than an image. You can use the codeblock formatting to properly format it and it will be searchable and usable for future visitors

Answer (score 5):

Since Mint is a Debian/Ubuntu derivative, the following should work:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

Your system should then display a list of the PHP versions that are installed on your system and you can manually choose one to become the default, like this:

```
There are 5 choices for the alternative php (providing /usr/bin/php).

  Selection    Path             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/php8.0   80        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/php7.0   70        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/php7.2   72        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/php7.3   73        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/php7.4   74        manual mode
Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

If you need Apache to run with an alternative PHP version as well, you can do this with the following commands (to switch from PHP 8.0 to PHP 7.4 for example):

```
sudo a2dismod php80
sudo a2enmod php74
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

As I see from your question that your PHP 7.4 installation was not complete because of a dependency issue, the above procedure will only work when this issue is resolved and all required PHP 7.4 packages have been installed.